# How do I style a table like a notepad?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a CSS/HTML version of this notepad on my page:

[image: notepad]

I was thinking of using a simple table like this:

```
<div id="notepad">
        <table> 
            <thead id="tbl_header">Comments</thead>     
            <tr></tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1">Dot</td>
                <td class="col2">Text for column 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"></td>
                <td class="col2"></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"></td>
                <td class="col2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"></td>
                <td class="col2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"></td>
                <td class="col2"></td>
                     <td class="col3"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </div>
```

So what I was thinking was cutting up the graphic. Have the top part, be the bg img for the `<thead>`.
Then just create one of the lines as the rows (there would be two graphics, one for col1 and col2 - so when a new row is created the bg of both columns would be populated), so that it can scale vertically as needed. Then, for the last set, I have two more graphics. One is for col1. One for col2 (which is the regular row but a little narrower in width) and the curl would be col3.

Is there a scalable way I can do this, using CSS & HTML only (no JS or jQuery) ?

Thanks.

P.S. Or is there another way to create this same thing without having to use bg images - and just using CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Using tables to do this is probably not correct (I assume your "notepad" isn't filled with tabular data); instead, a simple HTML5 `<section>` could be enough:

```
<section class="notepad">
    <header><h1>Comments</h1></header>
    <!-- Your text here -->
    <footer>&nbsp;</footer>
</section>
```

With appropriate CSS, this is easily styled to become a "notepad":

```
.notepad, .notepad>* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.notepad {
    background: url('middle-part.png');
}
.notepad header {
    background: url('top-part.png');
}
.notepad footer {
    background: url('curl-part.png');
    float: right;
    /* Set a correct size as well. */
}
```

Untested; may require some tweaking. Just be sure to set `line-height` appropriately, so that text doesn't overlap row lines. If you're using HTML4 (or even XHTML, *shrug*), simply replace the HTML5-specific elements with `<div>`s.

Comment: Interesting. You are right. There is no particular need for tabular data, except that I need the text to look like it is being written on a notepad (i.e. neatly on the lines). Will look into an implementation like this. Thanks.

Comment: Visual representation does not make it tabular. The general idea is that HTML should be semantic and non-presentational, i.e. HTML is *only* "what", not "how". Making text sit neatly on the lines can be done with the `line-height` property.

Comment: Btw @You...quick question. The notation `.notepad>*` basically means all the children of an element with the class 'notepad', right? From the first line of the CSS. Thanks.

Comment: @marcamillion: Yes, all *direct* children. Note that this is different from `.notepad *`, which selects *all* children (regardless of level). Read more about selectors here: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want the content to have *vertical rhythm*. It's very painstaking to achieve, but it's rewarding to do. Basically you select a line-height and then make everything have a vertical height that is some multiple of your chosen line-height. Here is a link that might better explain it as well as some tools that I use:

- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/14/technical-web-typography-guidelines-and-techniques/
- http://drewish.com/tools/vertical-rhythm
- http://pxtoem.com/